# 2002 Camaro ls1 wont start

Tags: chevrolet, starting, camaro

All the lights in my car work, but when I turn the key, you only hear the slightest click sound. Ive checked the starter and it tested fine. This is for a 2002 camaro ls1 engine.

Comment: It wont start what so ever.

Comment: Did you check the battery? When you try to start your car with lights on do they dim? They reason being that lights consume much less power compared to the starter moter

Comment: Check your connections at both the battery, the starter, and where the ground wire goes to the body.

Comment: You can always check the voltage with an multimeter if you are not sure if the battery works.

Comment: Did you check the starter motor relay in the fuse box? Also check the relevant fuse!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Check your battery voltage

If it's ok then there are three things that will cause this:

1. The security system - If the security light stays on then your key is not registering right with the ecu
2. The starter relay is faulty
3. The park neutral safety switch on the transmission is faulty

You have to check for these things in sequence before you get to the starter.